# Magento2 CLI module:enable gives error "Unkown module(s)"

Tags: magento2, module, error, magento-2.0, cli

In Magento2 I've built a simple custom module and want to enable it by CLI:

```
bin/magento module:enable Vendorname_Modulename
```

But it is giving me the following error:

> Unknown module(s): 'Vendorname_Modulename'

The module and it's files do exist in `app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/`

Of course I've cleared/disabled caches, cleared generation, Memcache(d) not running...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### `registration.php` missing

Apparently my `Vendorname_Modulename` module was missing the `registration.php`. I'm running the latest Magento2 version from GitHub.

Every module has to register itself in the `ComponentRegistrar`. A typical `registration.php` for a module (in the root of your module) could contain:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendorname_Modulename',
    __DIR__
);
```

Also see any Magento core component in [`app/code/Magento/`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/app/code/Magento) or your `vendor/magento/` dir

---

### `registration.php` NOT missing

In addition to this, if you DO have a `registration.php` file in your module, but you are still getting this error, this means that your `registration.php` was not loaded and Magento2 does not know about your module.

Your module should be under `app/code/` (where Magento2 will search folders in `app/code/` and find your module's `registration.php`), but if you have built your module as a Composer package, it will be in Composer's `vendor/` dir and you'll need to trick Composer into loading your module's `registration.php` (Magento doesn't search in `vendor/` by itself).

If you'd check any Magento2 module's `composer.json` in `vendor/magento/module-*`, you'll see an `"autoload"` section which references the `registration.php` file. So Composer will autoload your module's `registration.php` which will *"tell"* Magento2 where your module is located.

This is a fragment from the [Magento Checkout](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/composer.json) module's `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Checkout\\": ""
    }
}
```

If you have your module in a separate repository and loaded via composer, then the above is the way to go. If you do not have it in a separate repository, then your module does not belong on `vendor/` but in `app/code/`.

Comment: I got same error when I place the registration.php file under app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/etc folder by mistake

Comment: Good presentation.. well explained

Answer (score 7):

### Adding to: If `registration.php` NOT missing

Check and confirm if the module name in the module's `etc/module.xml`  is correct(not the module name in `<sequence>` tag if present)

[image]

Comment: Good addition! Also nice that you have illustrated it with a screenshot showing the exact field it is about +1

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
$name = implode('_', array_map(
    function($part) {
        return implode(array_map('ucfirst', explode('-', $part)));
    },
    array_slice(explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, __DIR__), -2, 2)
));
ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, $name, __DIR__);
```

You can use it for any extension without changing anything.
It works for any extension location (`app/code` or `vendor`) and for any extension type (module, translation dictionary).

Comment: Wow, this renders the presence of this file absolutely useless as it could be the same for every module. How about that for duplicate code... @Dimitry, you've beaten Magento2's dev team :P

Comment: This will not work for themes.

Comment: May I ask where this is to be used?

Answer (score 1):

This can also occur if permissions are not set correctly for the module directory and files. Ensure directory and files can be read by magento and web user.

Comment: Magento should not need write permissions on your module's code

Comment: I had this error today and restoring the permission for the module folder to 755 made this error dissapearing, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my `vendor` folder from the `app/code` was not created. I only had the module name. 
My module was in a zip file, so I unzipped it without the vendor folder.

Please make sure, you have both folders, otherwise you will get this error:
`Unknown module(s): 'Vendorname_Modulename'`

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by run `sudo composer remove <your-module>` remove the module directories in `vendor/<your-module>` & `app/code/<your-module>`.

Then reinstall the module again.

Note: replace the placeholder  by your module name.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error every time after running this command.

```
bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Dibay_Fooman_PdfCore
Unknown module(s): 'Dibay_Fooman_PdfCore'
```

??  and my directory structure was `app/code/Dibay/Fooman/PdfCore/` where my `registration.php` existed.

But after errors, I found my directory structure and made three new folders; I just changed it to two names in `Dibay/` dir. I added just one new folder, the name "`Fooman_PdfCore`", and now, the structure is like "`app/code/Dibay/Fooman_PdfCore/registration.php`" and the error was resolved successfully  with the following information.

```
sudo php -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content 
Dibay_Fooman_PdfCore
The following modules have been enabled:
- Dibay_Fooman_PdfCore
```

To make sure that the enabled modules are properly registered, run '`setup:upgrade`':

```
Cache cleared successfully.
Generated classes cleared successfully. Please run the 
'setup:di:compile' command to generate classes.
Generated static view files cleared successfully.
```